# Is there a way to select Google Photos that are not in an album using the Google Picker API?

Tags: google-photos, google-picker

I'm using the Google Picker API to select photos from Google Photos. The picker only shows photos in Albums. I would like to be able to choose pictures that are not in albums.

I followed the documentation and added the google photos view. I also tried adding recently uploaded photos option, but I think that is only for photos that were uploaded through the picker, not through Google Photos.

```
function createPicker() {
            if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
                var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
                addView(google.picker.ViewId.PHOTOS).
                setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
                setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
                setCallback(pickerCallback).
                build();
                picker.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
```

My expectation is that I'm able to select photos regardless if they are in an album or not. Currently I'm only able to select photos in albums.